# ¿ Es posible eliminar un elemento de un array en java?

Tags: java

¿ Es posible eliminar un elemento de un array en java ?
Tengo un array de char y me gustaría poder eliminar los espacios en blanco que hay en éste y los char repetidos. ejemplo del array de char [E, l, i, m, i, n, a, r,  , e, s, p, a, c, i, o, s,  , e, n,  , b, l, a, n, c, o,  , y,  , l, e, t, r, a, s,  , r, e, p, e, t, i, d, a, s]

Sin tener que crear un nuevo array y poner todos los elementos menos el que se quiere eliminar, o sin tener que "ocultar" el elemento que se quiere eliminar, es decir eliminarlo de memoria, si tengo el anterior array eliminar los que tenga el char n por ejemplo. Es posible hacer esto ?

Aunque no tengo código que acompañe mi pregunta, es más por concepto.

Comment: *Sin tener que crear un nuevo array y poner todos los elementos menos el que se quiere eliminar* -> No. Los array en java tienen longitud ***fija***. Para eso tendrás que usar otras colecciones como por ejemplo, un [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), que permite añadir/eliminar sin problema. La única opción usando arrays, es igualarlo a vacío por ejemplo, pero seguirá ocupando una posición en el array, ya que el tamaño del array no puede variar una vez instanciado

Comment: @Benito-B consulta, que hay de `ArrayUtils.remove()` ?? o similares ??

Comment: @Excorpion esas soluciones crean un nuevo arreglo y es el que te devuelven.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración !!!

Answer (score 1):

> ¿ Es posible eliminar un elemento de un array en java?

No

> ¿ Es posible agrandar un array en java?

No

> ¿ Es posible hacer mas pequeño un array en java?

No

> WTF

Quieres un List, seguramente un ArrayList. List es Collection. List es Iterable. List es amor.

Answer (score 0):

Los array definidos como
Ejemplo:
`String[] array = new String[n]`
Siempre tendran un tamaño fijo que sera n,podras sustituir valores, pero no borrar los indices, ya que el espacio en memoria ya se reservo.

Si quieres hacer cambios en un array la mejor manera es usar algun tipo de Collections, puede ser un List o un Set.

Si no te importa el orden con el cual agreges los elementos al arreglo puedes unsar HashSet, si quieres mantener el orden en el que agregas puedes usar un ArrayList.
Estos arreglos son dinamicos asi que puedes agregar y eliminar elementos sin problema.

Para este ejemplo usare un ArrayList

```
List arreglo = new ArrayList();
```

Asi creas la lista, despues agregas usando `arreglo.add(aqui pones tus letras);` y si quieres eliminar, haces un ciclo para recorrer el array y obtienes lo elementos con `arreglo.get(i)` aplicas las condiciones que quieras y para eliminar los elementos usas `arreglo.remove(i)`.

Solo en los Collections puedes eliminar sin que quede espacios vacios, en los arreglos primitivos no, la forma de "eliminar" es sustituyendo los valores.

Espero que te ayude.